# MySQL - Join and conditional select columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Don't know how to excatly name the problem. Therefore my example tables:

People:

```
id_people | peopleName |
------------------------
1         | John       |
2         | Jane       |
3         | Frank      |
4         | Emma       |
```

Courses:

```
id | id_course | id_people | date       |
-----------------------------------------
1  | 1         | 1         | 2011-02-14 |
2  | 2         | 1         | 2013-05-01 |
3  | 3         | 1         | 2015-08-25 |
4  | 1         | 2         | 2012-01-05 |
5  | 1         | 4         | 2017-10-10 |
```

Now I want to generate a table where I have one row per person and for every course a column with the date like:

```
id_people | peopleName | Course1    | Course2    | Course3    |
---------------------------------------------------------------
1         | John       | 2011-02-14 | 2013-05-01 | 2015-08-25 |
2         | Jane       | 2012-01-05 |            |            |
3         | Frank      |            |            |            |
4         | Emma       | 2017-10-10 |            |            |
```

I tried following query:

```sql
SELECT *,
 max(case when courses.id_course = 1 then cource.date end) as Course1,
 max(case when courses.id_course = 2 then cource.date end) as Course2,
 max(case when courses.id_course = 3 then cource.date end) as Course3  
FROM people
JOIN courses ON people.id_people = courses.id_people
GROUP BY people.id_people
```

But I got the error #1055 ([..] this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by).
So, it forces me to add the column course.id, course.id_course and course.date to the group by statemant. This results in a row per per people and course.
How can I get my desired resulting table with a sql statment?
I do not have the privilege to change the sql_mode variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So it forces me to add the column course.id, course.id_course and
>   course.date to the group by statemant...

No it does not.
You only need to change the join to a `LEFT JOIN` and `group by people.id_people, people.peopleName` and you will get the results that you want:

```
SELECT people.id_people, people.peopleName,
 max(case when courses.id_course = 1 then courses.date end) as Course1,
 max(case when courses.id_course = 2 then courses.date end) as Course2,
 max(case when courses.id_course = 3 then courses.date end) as Course3  
FROM people
LEFT JOIN courses ON people.id_people = courses.id_people
GROUP BY people.id_people, people.peopleName
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rVAaWi4ofVFLjRyDJfshv4/1).
Results:

```
| id_people | peopleName | Course1     | Course2     | Course3     |
| --------- | ---------- | ----------- | ----------- | ----------- |
| 1         | John       | 2011-02-14  | 2013-05-01  | 2015-08-25  |
| 2         | Jane       | 2012-01-05  |             |             |
| 3         | Frank      |             |             |             |
| 4         | Emma       | 2017-10-10  |             |             |
```

Comment: I see where I made the failure. The * in the select leads to error. When I only add the columns p.id_people and p.peopleName in the select statment it works, like you say. But due the fact that my real table is much bigger with more data, is there a way that I do not have to add each column to the group by statment?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't define `id_people` to be a `primary key` or at least `unique`.  You should probably do that.

In the meantime, you can aggregate first and then `join`:

```
SELECT *
FROM people p JOIN
     (SELECT c.id_people
             max(case when c.id_course = 1 then c.date end) as Course1,
             max(case when c.id_course = 2 then c.date end) as Course2,
             max(case when c.id_course = 3 then c.date end) as Course3  
      FROM courses c
      GROUP BY c.id_people
     ) c
     USING (id_people);
```